# React class calling function via button click to change Constructor value

Tags: reactjs

This is my code, i rarely use react but now i need to make a project in it, basically i want these blocks to act as separate Objects, each with its unique data, there is a button that changes the view variable with the function cycle, but its just throws me errors. React is so confusing.

```
class Block
{
  constructor(tag, view) {
    this.tag = tag;
    this.view = view; 

    function cycle(){
      if(this.view < 3){
        this.view = this.view + 1;
      }else{
        this.view = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
    <Draggable>
      <div className="Block" onClick={cycle()}>
        <input type='Button'/>
        {this.view == 0 &&
        //HTML
        <div>
          <img src ={html_bg} draggable="false"/>
          <p>&lt;{this.tag}&gt;Inner HTML&lt;/{this.tag}&gt;</p>
        </div>
        }
        {this.view == 1 &&
        //CSS
        <div>
          <img src ={css_bg} draggable="false"/>
        </div>
        }
        {this.view == 2 &&
        //JS
        <div>
          <img src ={js_bg} draggable="false"/>
        </div>
        }
      </div>
      </Draggable>
    )
  }
}
```

I expect that when the button is pressed on a "Block" object it changes the view value and rerenders the block to show the state i need.